# Sitecore datasource query by comparing pubDate to current date RSS Feeds

Tags: sitecore-query, rss

So I have this query:

`query:$home//[@@name='blogs']//[@@templatename='BlogArticle' and contains(@date, '202208')]`

It works fine, but my goal is to compare the value of the @date field to the current date. Is there a way to get the current date in Sitecore?

My goal is to have something like this: `query:$home//[@@name='blogs']//[@@templatename='BlogArticle' and @date >= @_currentdate - 2`

I would like to be able to compare blog publishing dates to the current date and make sure they were published in the last 2 months.

Currently, Sitecore is pulling up to the RSS Feed limit of 50 and then sorting by date. (Hence not getting the most recent blogs published).

Or is there a better way? I'm open to any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like there is any default option to provide the kind of search capabilities you need. One option would be to create a custom "FeedItem" and implement the search filtering/sorting you need. You could also take advantage of the Content Search API to speed things up.

I found an article shared by a member of the community that could help.

https://www.sitecorespark.com/blog/2020/6/creating-and-customizing-an-rss-feed-in-sitecore